# iText 5 - How to set cells of a table in different sizes using iText 5 in Java

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am writing a Java code to generate a PDF template. In the pdf's header section, I have created a pdfTable which has 7 cells including an image cell (Logo), a text field (Id Number) and remaining 5 cells to populate the actual Id Number.

In the output, I should get a bigger image cell (representing the Logo) and Id number cells must be smaller in size than the image cell. Example, as in the below image (Expected Result).

[image: Expected Result]

However when the template is generated, I am unable populate as expected as shown in the above image (Expected Result).

When the PDF is generated, all the cells are taking the size of the image cell.

I have tried with different approaches like setting column widhts, setFixedHeight(), setRowSpan(), setColumnSpan() methods etc. But nothing worked. Below image shows my output (Current Output).

[image: Current Output]

Below is code which I have written.

```
public class NbaBafTemplateGenerator {

        private void createNbaBafTemplate(File outPutfileName, NbaBafTemplateData formData,String logoName) {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outPutfileName));
                document.open();
                PdfPTable table = null;

    // Passing the data as a single String                      

              //IdNumber varible is of type String and has 5 characters of the number.
                table = NbaBafTemplatePage.createHeaderTable(logoName + ",Id Number: , " + 
                formData.getIdNumber(), 7, "", "","1.5f, 1f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f"); 
                document.add(table); 

    }// END OF CLASS NbaBafTemplateGenerator.



    //Class NbaBafTemplatePage  Begins.
    public class NbaBafTemplatePage extends PdfPageEventHelper {

        public static PdfPTable createHeaderTable(String text, int columnCount, String colour, String align, String colSize)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {

                    PdfPTable table = null;
                    table = new PdfPTable(columnCount); // 7 columns.
                    table.setWidthPercentage(100); // Width 100%
                    table.setSpacingBefore(0f); /
                    table.setSpacingAfter(10f);

              //Assigning column widths based on input width params.                
                float[] tablecolumnWidths = {
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[0]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[1]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[2]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[3]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[4]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[5]),
                        Float.parseFloat(colSize.split(",")[6])};   

            PdfPCell imgCell = new PdfPCell(createImageCell(text.split(",")[0]));

                    //imgCell.setColspan(3);
                    //imgCell.setRowspan(3);
                    imgCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                    imgCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    imgCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    table.addCell(imgCell);


            PdfPCell idCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[1]));

                    idCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
                    idCell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    idCell.setPaddingLeft(10);
                    idCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    idCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    table.addCell(idCell);

            PdfPCell cellC0 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[2]));

                cellC0.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK); 
                cellC0.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cellC0.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(cellC0);

           PdfPCell cellC1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[3]));

                cellC1.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK); 
                cellC1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cellC1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(cellC1);

           PdfPCell cellC2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[4]));

                cellC2.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK); 
                cellC2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cellC2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(cellC2);

           PdfPCell cellC3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[5]));

                cellC3.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK); 
                cellC3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                cellC3.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                table.addCell(cellC3);

           PdfPCell cellC4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(text.split(",")[6]));
           cellC4.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK); 
           cellC4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
           cellC4.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
           table.addCell(cellC4);

    return table;
    }//END OF METHOD createHeaderTable.

        public static PdfPCell createImageCell(String path) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Image img = Image.getInstance(path);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);

        return cell;
    }
  }
```

I am using Java and iText 5.x version.

Can anyone please let me know how to generate the pdf table with different cell sizes.

Comment: Identical question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112828/how-to-set-cells-of-a-table-in-different-sizes-using-itext5-in-java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table with 2 rows (13 cells). Set the column-span of image cell equal to 2. Keep the remaining cells of the first row as blank, set their borders as 0 (invisible), and adjust their heights (cells of the first row) as per your required alignment. 
Then add the remaining 6 cells to the table as a second row. Adjust column widths as per your requirement. Hope this helps.

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);         
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell(image);       
    imageCell.setBorder(0);
    imageCell.setRowspan(2);        
    table.addCell(imageCell);

    for(int i=0; i<6;i++) {
        PdfPCell blankCell = new PdfPCell();
        blankCell.setBorder(0);
        blankCell.setFixedHeight(20f);
        table.addCell(blankCell);
    }

    PdfPCell cell22 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ID Number"));
    table.addCell(cell22);

    PdfPCell cell23 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("9"));                
    table.addCell(cell23);

    PdfPCell cell24 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("6"));        
    table.addCell(cell24);

    PdfPCell cell25 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("0"));        
    table.addCell(cell25);

    PdfPCell cell26 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("5"));        
    table.addCell(cell26);

    PdfPCell cell27 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1"));        
    table.addCell(cell27);      

    document.add(table);
```

Comment: Hi Prasad, Sorry for the delay. I tested this only today. Your solution is perfectly working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Prasad, Where do I find the Accept tick mark? please let me know.